# Convert $22202_3$ (in base $3$) into base $11$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-systems

> Convert $22202_3$ (in base $3$) into base $11$.

I know I can just convert into base $10$ and divide by $11$.

$2\times 3^4+2\times3^3+2\times3^2+2=236_{10}$

Then repeated division by $11$ yields $(1A5)_{11}$, which is the correct answer. However, I would like to do it directly through long division and I'm getting stuck.

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
11&2&2&2&0&2 \\
&&&2&1& -5\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Explanation for what I'm doing:
A single $2$ in base $3$ is not divisible by $11$. Neither is $22 \ (2\times3+2=8)$. So take $222 \ (2\times3^2+2\times3+2 = 26)$. $11$ goes into $26$ two times with $4$ remainder. Write down the $2$. The $4$ remainder is carried to the next digit, $0$, making $40 \ (4\times3+0=12)$. $11$ goes into $12$ one time, so write down $1$. The remainder, also $1$, is carried to the next digit, $2$. The next position $12 \ (1\times3+2=5)$ is not divisible by $11$, hence the remainder is $5$, which is written as $-5$.

Now I can't go on, because $21$ in base $3$ is equivalent to $2\times3+2=8$, which isn't divisible by $11$. Something is obviously wrong, but I can't see it, because I did get the digit $5$, which is in the correct position and is part of the correct answer.

Comment: We have had (many) questions about direct conversion from one base to another. I suggest you search for one of those earlier questions.

Comment: In that long division tableau, it may be clearer to write the $11_{10}$ on the left as $102$ (in base $3$).

Comment: Your last step was to divide $12_3$ by $102_3$, and you didn't record the quotient $0$. The overall division, $22202_3$ by $102_3$, has quotient $210_3$ and remainder $12_3 = 5_{11}$. The $5_{11}$ matches the units digit of $1A5_{11}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the units digit of $1A5_{11}$, you tried to perform division with remainder of $22202_3$ by $11_{10} = 102_3$.

Your last step was to divide $12_3$ by $102_3$, and you didn't record the quotient $0$. The overall quotient $210_3$ is the one for the next step to calculate the "elevens" digit. The remainder $5_{11}$ matches the units digit of $1A5_{11}$.

Explicitly in long division:

$$
\begin{array}{ r|ccccccc }
&&& 2&1&0 \\
\hline 
102& 2&2&2&0&2 \\
& 2&1&1\\
\hline
&& 1&1&0 \\
&& 1&0&2 \\
\hline
&&&& 1&2 \\
&&&&& 0
\\
\hline
&&&& 1&2 & (= 5_{11}) \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: +1 for the effort involved in generating the long division in $\mathrm\LaTeX$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The OP started this tableau in an admittedly similar question [In base $12$, divide $15et20$ by $9$ where $e=11$ and $t=10$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4822704/89922)